# std::mt19937 mersenne twister distribution with non repeating values

Tags: c++, random

I'd like to use the std::mt19937 random number generator to produce a list of numbers between 0 and 255.
"Once a number has been chosen, it should not appear again in the set." - it's this bit I don't know how to do.  The mathematical term for this escapes me(!)

```
std::mt19937                        twister;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distribution;

twister.seed(91210);
distribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,255);

std::vector vNumbers;
vNumbers.resize(256);

for( int n = 0; n < 256; ++ n )
    vNumbers[n] = distribution(twister);
```

Comment: Do you need to retain the order in which they are produced?

Comment: No, order doesn't matter; I want random order :)

Comment: What I mean is, if you use `std::set` to get uniqueness, your numbers get sorted. I.e. if you generate `57 1 9 44 102 1` and store it in a `std::set`, you get back `1 9 44 57 102`. Is this acceptable? (And you keep generating until `mySet.size()==255`).

Comment: Oh I see. You want exactly the integer `0-255` inclusive, in some random order, correct? If so, you could fill the `std::vector` with `0 1 ... 255` with [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), then get random order with [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle).

Comment: @fishfood Why do you shout your requirements "I want [this particular thing]" when you just said "order doesn't matter"? Clearly, it _does_ matter, then?

Comment: Oh, ordered numbers wouldn't be desirable.  And using a vector is preferred, since I'm copying the data to the GPU.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's algorithms for that:

```
// fill a vector ith [0..255]:
std::vector<int> vNumbers(256);
std::iota(vNumbers.begin(), vNumbers.end(), 0);

// shuffle it
std::random_shuffle(vNumbers.begin(), vNumbers.end());

// done
```

With C++11 you can pass in your own generator for the RNG: (see also comments)

```
std::shuffle(vNumbers.begin(), vNumbers.end(), twister);
```

Or you could roll your own (google Fisher-Yates, or see Knuth)

---

Of course the `iota` can be replaced by te following

```
for (int i=0; i<256; ++i) vNumbers[i] = i;
```

Comment: And you can even use a random engine to shuffle the numbers!

Comment: One potential problem with rolling your own is modulo bias. With a power of two it's not a problem (assuming the PRNG outputs numbers 0 .. 2^w or the signed equivalent) but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @delnan It's a bit ludicrous to mention only that :/ But yeah: the background for that: http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx

Comment: The function passed to `random_shuffle` needs to take an argument for the range. You should use `std::shuffle` instead, and you don't need the distribution then.

Comment: @Interjay/Xeo http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle. Added a sample to the answer.

Comment: @sehe What other problems do you think are worth mentioning? The period of a MT19937 should be plenty for all permutations of reasonably sized sets (for some definition of "reasonably sized"), and other implementation pitfalls are generally taken care of by the PRNG, not by the short loop adapting it to the shuffle.

Comment: @sehe My comment was about the sample you added, which is incorrect.

Comment: @interjay Except that it's not incorrect: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1353738d014e7a3ac0f97d13d2f6ee93-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68 or http://ideone.com/elp3IF

Comment: @sehe it is correct with the given distribution, but would fail with for example `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>  distribution(0,1255);` it is worth mentioning this detail. Therefore the `std::shuffle` variant is easier to use.

Comment: @KillianDS Okay. I can see your point. Will modify the sample. However, I tend to assume that the programmer knows what he's doing once he starts selecting his/her own PRNG and distributions :) **Edit** Anything else to add: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b43b67298dcc9da034fc43029c7f831a-542192d2d8aca3c820c7acc656fa0c68?

Comment: @KillianDS,sehe Actually, the previous code was incorrect even with the (0,255) distribution. The random function is supposed to take an argument `n` and return a number in the range [0,n). The function that was given here ignored the argument and returned a number in the range [0,256), making it undefined behavior. The current version with `std::shuffle` is correct.

Comment: @interjay In fact, we've worked out **[in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=10932943#10932943)** that actually, the argument passed by `random_shuffle` was being silently ignored (explaining how it wasn't a compilation error). Yes, this was confusing, but no, it wasn't actually UB.

Comment: @sehe It's UB because the program violates the constraints given by the standard on how the function is supposed to behave: "the call rand(n) shall return a randomly chosen value in the interval [0,n)".

Comment: It's actually stronger than "might". It will almost certainly call it with n!=256. See for example the implementation given in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle. While it did seem to work for you, the results were actually not distributed evenly.

Comment: @interjay Completely agreeing. I learned something. Chief among which being that `std::bind` can hide a number of issues from view silently.  I think it's sad that C++11 with all the safety it's added has been introducing such tricky pitfalls back into the standard library. Thanks for your continued explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead of `std::vector`, as it will ensure you have no duplicates. Just loop until the size of the set is the number of value you want.

---

Since it seems you want one of each number in just a random order, you don't really need to generate random numbers, just generate a sequence from 0 to 255, and then randomly shuffle them.

This can easily be done with some [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), like [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) and [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle):

```
std::vector<int> values{256};
std::iota(values.begin(), values.end(), 0);
std::random_shuffle(values.begin(), values.end());
```

Comment: what about the case where the RNG generates a repeat and it's inserted into the set.  if the set rejects it, I'm left with < 255 numbers in my set.  I'm looking for a way to instruct the random number generator not to issue any repeating data.

Comment: I should also point out that I'm copying this data into a texture for use in a shader program, so using a vector is also desirable for ease of copying the data to the gfx card.

Comment: @fishfood Continue until the size of the set is the number of values you want. And it's easy to copy a set to a vector when needed.

Comment: I know that's one way to pluck the turkey, but I'd like to find a way to instruct the random number generator not to issue any repeating data.  I'm sure it exists :)

Comment: @fishfood The thing about random numbers is that they are random, even a series of ten of the same number can be considered random. See e.g. http://xkcd.com/221/ for a humorous (but valid) take on it.

Comment: @sehe Because I didn't see yours.